# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Tags: xcode

I am getting 2 errors when I run this project, the one in the title and ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7. Look t pictures. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, looked at every other post about this and non worked. Thank you so much for your support, if you have any questions please ask and i will let you know!

**Image on my website, they wont let me post any here.** 
***Image Link:http://www.nicmacengineering.com/image**

THANKS SOOOOO MUCH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because the file JARRightViewController is not added to the target..

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/tutorials/ios-oauth2-tutorial/compiler_flags.png

Follow that image... Under "Compile Sources" click the '+' sign, and a pop up will be shown with your project files... pick the JARRightViewController.m from there.. and click add.

Answer (score 1):

What are JARightViewController and JASidePanelController?

Make sure the files are added to your project target, look in the Build Phases: Compile Sources. If they are not there add them.

Comment: It wants to work, but when I do exactly what you told me to it just gets stuck compiling 2 sources and never runs on my device? Thanks!